# bootstrap-select disappears when I switch to another page

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, bootstrap-select

I am trying to add bootstrap-select to one of my projects, it displays fine when the application loads and the URL is manually hit but when I switch to another page using routing, the selects disappear.

[When I start the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiNbS.jpg)

[After I switch the page and return to the same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyn1M.jpg)

My app.module.ts is like this:

```
@NgModule({

declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    VehiclesComponent,
    VehicleDetailComponent,
    VehicleEditComponent,
    VehicleListComponent,
    VehicleItemComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    MiniSearchComponent,
    AdvancedSearchComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The angular.json file

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css",            
          "src/styles.css"
          ],
 "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"
           ]
```

I am using `<router-outlet>` to change the pages, all the other components and controls load fine, with the exception of bootstrap-select select

Thank you for your time

Comment: You must call `$('.select').selectpicker();` in `onInit()` method as first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking around I found the solution to this problem:

First need to add the types package for jQuery using the following command

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Second add the following line to the tslint.json file:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

Third add this declaration to the .ts file where you are using the select, it has to be right after the imports:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Fourth implement `AfterViewInit` and in add the following code:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}
```

For this work you must have already installed correctly bootstrap 4, jQuery ,popper and bootstrap-select

I hope this helps someone else